# Can SAS Score a Data Set to an ARIMA Model?

Tags: sas

Is it possible to score a data set with a model created by PROC ARIMA in SAS?

This is the code I have that is not working:

```
proc arima data=work.data;
identify var=x crosscorr=(y(7) y(30));
estimate outest=work.arima;
run;

proc score data=work.data score=work.arima type=parms predict out=pred;
var x;
run;
```

When I run this code I get an error from the PROC SCORE portion that says "ERROR: Variable x not found."  The x column is in the data set work.data.

Comment: Can you show the data?

Comment: You would typically use the FORECAST statement within PROC ARIMA for forecasts. Scoring a dataset is a bit different in time series data and PROC SCORE wants a linear model so I doubt this would work as expected.

Comment: @Dinesh.hmn unfortunately I can't show the data for confidentiality reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`proc score` does not support autocorrelated variables. The simplest way to get an out-of-sample score is to combine both `proc arima` and a `data` step. Here's an example using `sashelp.air`.

**Step 1: Generate historical data**

We leave out the year 1960 as our score dataset.

```
data have;
    set sashelp.air;
    where year(date) < 1960;
run;
```

**Step 2: Generate a model and forecast**

The `nooutall` option tells `proc arima` to only produce the 12 future forecasts.

```
proc arima data=have;
    identify var=air(12);
    estimate p=1 q=(2) method=ml;
    forecast lead=12 id=date interval=month out=forecast nooutall;
run;
```

**Step 3: Score**

Merge together your forecast and full historical dataset to see how well the model did. I personally like the [`update` statement](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/69738/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p18w3br45er2qun1r8sfmm4grjyr.htm) because it will not replace anything with missing values.

```
data want;
    update forecast(in=fcst) 
           sashelp.air(in=historical);
    by Date;

    /* Generate fit statistics */
    Error    = Forecast-Air;
    PctError = Error/Air;
    AbsPctError = abs(PctError);

    /* Helpful for bookkeeping */
    if(fcst) then Type = 'Score';
        else if(historical) then Type = 'Est';

    format PctError AbsPctError percent8.2;
run;
```

You can take this code and convert it into a generalized macro for yourself. That way in the future, if you wanted to score something, you could simply call a macro program to get what you need.